# "general assuan error" in gpa under linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnupg

I'm trying to use gpa to manage my gpg keys under linux mint and am getting a "general assuan error" whenever I try to run the application. If I run as root, gpa works fine but I'd prefer to not need to sudo just to see my personal keys. I've tried running chmod u+s without any luck. What else can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

While I am not 100% sure what actually happens but `gpa` will start with `gpa --disable-x509`, which can be edited into the `gpa.desktop` file under `Exec=`.